# SAS proc Surveryselect choose sample from different strata with different percentages

Tags: sas

I have a population with 5 different strata, I want to take a random sample 
 of size n from a pool that is consisted of 100% from stratum 1, 10% from 
 stratum 2, 20% from stratum 3, etc.

How can I accomplish it in a proc surveyselect step?

Thanks.

Comment: Use the SAMPSIZE option.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SAMPRATE option within PROC SURVEYSELECT.
https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_surveyselect_sect007.htm

> SAMPRATE=(values)
>
> RATE=(values)
>
> specifies stratum sampling rates, where the stratum sampling rate is the proportion of units to select from the stratum. You can separate values with blanks or commas. The number of SAMPRATE= values must equal the number of strata in the input data set.
> List the stratum sampling rate values in the order in which the strata appear in the input data set. When you use the SAMPRATE=(values) option, the input data set must be sorted by the STRATA variables in ascending order. You cannot use the DESCENDING or NOTSORTED option in the STRATA statement.
> Each stratum sampling rate value must be a nonnegative. You can specify a rate value as a number between 0 and 1. Or you can specify a rate value in percentage form as a number between 1 and 100, and PROC SURVEYSELECT converts that number to a proportion. The procedure treats the value 1 as 100% instead of 1%.
> To select a sample from a stratum, the value of the stratum sampling rate must be positive. If you specify a stratum sampling rate of 0, then PROC SURVEYSELECT does not select a sample from the stratum. This has the effect of subsetting the input data set before sample selection; the stratum that you omit is not included in the sampling frame or represented in the sample.
> The SAMPRATE= option is available only for equal probability selection methods (METHOD=SRS, METHOD=URS, METHOD=SYS, and METHOD=SEQ). For systematic random sampling (METHOD=SYS), PROC SURVEYSELECT uses the inverse of the stratum sampling rate as the interval for the stratum. See the section Systematic Random Sampling for details about systematic sampling. For other selection methods, PROC SURVEYSELECT converts the stratum sampling rate to a stratum sample size before selection by multiplying the total number of units in the stratum by the sampling rate and rounding up to the nearest integer.